# Quickblox Android how to get the first message from incoming chat?

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm using quickblox android sdk for my chat application. I know that when opponent user starts the conversation QBPrivateChatManagerListener -> chatCreated() event get fired. Below is my code. When chatCreated is fired I load the chat Fragment. In the chat fragment I have implemented the QBMessageListenerImpl interface. Problem here is that I don't get the first message from processMessage(). But I get the second message. So my question is how can I read the very first message that opponent user is sending ?

```
  @Override
    public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat qbPrivateChat, boolean b) {
        ShowMessage("Incoming chat!!");
        if(!b)
        {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CreateNewChatForIncoming(qbPrivateChat);
                }
            });
        }
    }

     public void CreateNewChatForIncoming(QBPrivateChat qbPrivateChat) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        PrivateChatFragment privateChatFragment = new PrivateChatFragment();
        privateChatFragment.setOpponentuser(null);
        privateChatFragment.setIncomingChat(qbPrivateChat);
        HashMap<Integer, QBUser> allusers = applicationSingleton.getAllusers();
        String title = allusers.get(qbPrivateChat.getParticipant()).getFullName();
        if (title != null)
            this.setTitle(title);

        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, privateChatFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }




    /*---------------Private chat Fragment-------------------------*/

    public class PrivateChatFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    TextView txtmsg;
    MessageAdaptor messageAdaptor;
    ListView listView;
    boolean ismode = true;
    PrivateChat privateChat;

    private QBUser opponentuser;
    private QBPrivateChat incomingChat;
    int opponentuserid;
    ApplicationSingleton applicationSingleton;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chattabfragment, container, false);
        txtmsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
        SetFont(txtmsg);
        applicationSingleton = (ApplicationSingleton)getSherlockActivity().getApplication();
        messageAdaptor = new MessageAdaptor(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.msg_list_item_inbound);

        if (opponentuser != null) {
            opponentuserid = opponentuser.getId();
            HashMap<Integer, PrivateChat> allpvtchats = applicationSingleton.getAllpvtchats();
            if(allpvtchats.containsKey(opponentuserid)) {
                privateChat = applicationSingleton.getAllpvtchats().get(opponentuserid);
            }
            else {
                privateChat = new PrivateChat(this, opponentuserid);
                applicationSingleton.getAllpvtchats().put(opponentuserid,privateChat);
            }
            List<ChatMessage> allmsgs = GetMessageHistory(opponentuser);
            if (allmsgs != null) {
                ShowMessage("setting history");
                messageAdaptor.LoadNewItems(allmsgs);
                messageAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                messageAdaptor.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        } else if (incomingChat != null) {
            opponentuserid = incomingChat.getParticipant();
            privateChat = new PrivateChat(this, incomingChat);
        }

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_msg);
        listView.setAdapter(messageAdaptor);
        txtmsg.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
                    msg.setOutbound(true);
                    msg.setImg(R.drawable.boy1);
                    msg.setTime("10:30am");
                    msg.setMessage(txtmsg.getText().toString());
                    messageAdaptor.add(msg);
                    txtmsg.setText("");
                    scrolToBottom();

                    QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
                    chatMessage.setBody(msg.getMessage());
                    //chatMessage.setProperty("name", opponentuser.getFullName());
                    chatMessage.setSaveToHistory(true);
                    chatMessage.setMarkable(true);
                    try {
                        privateChat.sendMessage(chatMessage);
                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        ApplicationSingleton applicationSingleton = (ApplicationSingleton) this.getActivity().getApplication();
        HashMap<Integer, List<ChatMessage>> allchats = applicationSingleton.getAllchats();
        allchats.put(opponentuserid, messageAdaptor.GetAllMessages());
        applicationSingleton.setAllchats(allchats);
    }

    private List<ChatMessage> GetMessageHistory(QBUser opnnentuser) {
        ApplicationSingleton applicationSingleton = (ApplicationSingleton) this.getActivity().getApplication();
        HashMap<Integer, List<ChatMessage>> allchats = applicationSingleton.getAllchats();

        if (allchats.containsKey(opnnentuser.getId())) {
            return allchats.get(opnnentuser.getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    void SetFont(TextView view) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/LatoRegular.ttf");
        view.setTypeface(font);
    }

    public void scrolToBottom() {
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelection(messageAdaptor.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }


    public void UpdateAdaptor(final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (messageAdaptor != null) {
                    messageAdaptor.add(chatMessage);
                    messageAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    scrolToBottom();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void setOpponentuser(QBUser opponentuser) {
        this.opponentuser = opponentuser;
    }

    public void setIncomingChat(QBPrivateChat incomingChat) {
        this.incomingChat = incomingChat;
    }

    public void SendNotification(String title, String message) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getSherlockActivity())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.boy6_small)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message);
        int mId = GetNotificationid();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), SideMenuActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(GlobalData.OP_ID, opponentuser.getId());
        resultIntent.putExtra(GlobalData.NOTIFY_MODE, true);
        resultIntent.putExtra(GlobalData.NOTIFY_ID, mId);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getSherlockActivity());
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(SideMenuActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }


    private void ShowMessage(final String msg) {
        Runnable mrunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(mrunnable);
    }

    private int GetNotificationid()
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int milsec = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        return  milsec;
    }
}

/* --------------------Privatechat class------------------- */    
  public class PrivateChat extends QBMessageListenerImpl<QBPrivateChat>{  
    private QBPrivateChatManager privateChatManager;  
    private QBPrivateChat privateChat;  
    private PrivateChatFragment currentContext;  
    private ApplicationSingleton applicationSingleton;  

    public PrivateChat(PrivateChatFragment context,Integer opponentID) {
        currentContext = context;
        applicationSingleton = (ApplicationSingleton)currentContext.getSherlockActivity().getApplication();
        privateChatManager = applicationSingleton.getChatService().getPrivateChatManager();
        // init private chat
        //
        privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentID);
        if (privateChat == null) {
            privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentID, this);
        }else{
            privateChat.addMessageListener(this);
        }
    }

    public PrivateChat(PrivateChatFragment context,QBPrivateChat incomingChat) {
        privateChat = incomingChat;
        privateChat.addMessageListener(this);
        currentContext = context;
    }

    public void sendMessage(QBChatMessage message) throws XMPPException, SmackException.NotConnectedException {
        privateChat.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void release() {
        privateChat.removeMessageListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat chat, QBChatMessage message) {
        Log.e("Anuradha-message",message.getBody());

        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
        msg.setOutbound(false);
        msg.setImg(R.drawable.boy2);
        msg.setTime("10:30am");
        msg.setMessage(message.getBody());
        currentContext.UpdateAdaptor(msg);

        if(applicationSingleton.isAppBackground()) {
            HashMap<Integer,QBUser> allusers = applicationSingleton.getAllusers();
            QBUser user = allusers.get(message.getSenderId());
            currentContext.SendNotification(user.getFullName().toString(),"says "+message.getBody());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void processError(QBPrivateChat chat, QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originChatMessage){

    }


    @Override
    public void processMessageDelivered(QBPrivateChat privateChat, String messageID){

    }

    @Override
    public void processMessageRead(QBPrivateChat privateChat, String messageID){
        ShowMessage("msg read : "+messageID);
    }


    private void ShowMessage(final String msg) {
        Runnable mrunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(currentContext.getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        currentContext.getActivity().runOnUiThread(mrunnable);
    }



}
```

Comment: think we need more code than that to work out what is going on. FYI method names should start with a lowercase letter as convention in Java so as to not cause confusion with class names

Comment: thanks for the information. I'm a .net programmer. So I'm not familiar with the java convention. So thanks again for the information and I have added the full source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
privateChat = privateChatManager.getChat(opponentID);`enter code here`        if (privateChat == null) {
        privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentID, this);
    }else{
        privateChat.addMessageListener(this);
    }
```

**to**

```
if (privateChat == null) {
        privateChat = privateChatManager.createChat(opponentID, this);
    }
    privateChat.addMessageListener(this);
```